# Link of two "Nebensätze" with "damit"

Tags: sentence-structure

I would like to ask if the following sentence is correct:

> *Ich habe mit einer Beamtin die letzte Woche gesprochen und sie hat mich gesagt, dass ich meinen Lebenslauf vorlegen muss, **damit** sie ihm nach Tübingen schickt.*

Since "damit" links a "Hauptsatz" with a "Nebensatz", would it be correct to say something like that?

Comment: "damit" joins a subclause to something else. There is no rule whatsoever that the *other* thing must be a main clause. That is a good thing, because otherwise there would be sentences which are impossible to render into reported speech accurately.

Comment: @Em1 I don't think the *die* between *Beamtin* and *letzte Woche* was addressed by the answer (contrary to *mich* and *ihm*) and it looks and sounds so wrong to my eyes and ears. Can it be re-edited away?

Comment: @Em1 I wanted the collateral mistakes to get out of the way of the real issue, but perhaps you're right, thus they would have slipped from the OP's attention.

Comment: @Jan Since Ingmar changed the word order, it's not that obvious, but basically the "die" was removed. I wouldn't want to edit again.

Answer (score 2):

A more idiomatic version would be:

> Ich habe letzte Woche mit einer Beamtin gesprochen und sie hat *mir* gesagt, dass ich meinen Lebenslauf vorlegen muss, damit sie *ihn* nach Tübingen schickt.

Comment: so "damit" can also link two Nebensätze?

Comment: Why, how does my version differ, apart from word order and mir/mich and ihm/ihn?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot understand the difference i am now learning some german...

Comment: @VassilisDe You just have to read Ingmar's version, there *is* a difference.

Comment: Shouldn't we also point to the differences that mainly come from the correct use of grammatical cases here? This may not be so obvious for a learner.

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence is not correct, but that is due to word order and grammar, as Ingmar pointed out in the older answer, not due to the *damit*.

*Damit* does not *link* two clauses (main and/or subordinate clause to subordinate clause), but it rather *opens* a subordinate clause. Compare the following examples:

> **Damit** ich heute noch mit meiner Arbeit fertigwerde, mache ich eine kürzere Mittagspause.
>   Wenn ich die Sonnenbrille aufsetzen muss, **damit** ich etwas sehe, muss es hell am Himmel sein.
>   Ich gehe in die Schule, **damit** ich etwas lerne.

The only common feature of these three sentences is that whatever followes *damit* until the next comma (or full stop) is a subordinate clause (a final clause, if you want to be exact). It states the purpose of the part it is related to; usually the preceding clause, but if there is no preceding one (first example) the following clause. So it *is* possible for *damit* to stand between two subordinate clauses.

---

Your grammar issues boil down to wrong cases: *jemandem etwas sagen* requires the dative for the person (*sie hat mir gesagt*), and *etwas wohin schicken* requires the accusative for the object (*sie hat ihn geschickt*).